# SQL - multi select query returning no results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I'm trying to select a Row Number from a table that meets a certain criteria from a separate table.

The current query returns 0 results when I'm expecting 1 number

```
SELECT 
    RowNum 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ID, Name, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) 
     FROM
         tblEncroachmentTypes) AS temp
WHERE
    temp.Name LIKE (SELECT EN_TYPE 
                    FROM LakeEncroachments 
                    WHERE EN_ID = '0526')
```

I have created a temp table to try and simplify it, but it still returns no results

```
select RowNum 
from #temp1 
where #temp1.Name like (select EN_TYPE from LakeEncroachments where EN_ID = '0526')
```

I'm trying to give as much information as possible, but not sure what else I need.

Comment: `when I'm expecting 1 number` ..how are you expecting one number,does the table contain any data..also does this work..`SELECT RowNum from (Select ID, Name, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) from tblEncroachmentTypes) as temp
where temp.Name Like (Select EN_TYPE from LakeEncroachments WHERE EN_ID = '0526')`

Comment: @TheGameiswar There should be one result. The row number of the given encroachment type. If I use where temp.Name like 'multi-slip dock' I get the expected result. 
The query you suggested does not give me a result

Comment: if the query returns data with `where temp.Name like 'multi-slip dock'`, then you need to look at the lookup query itself.  What value does `select EN_TYPE from LakeEncroachments where EN_ID = '0526'` return? If it doesn't return 'multi-slip dock', there's your problem.  If it returns something that looks like 'multi-slip dock', then try running `select 1 where 'multi-slip dock' like (select EN_TYPE from LakeEncroachments where EN_ID = '0526')`, as it could be data type or even collation that is making them not match.

Comment: @SlimsGhost There was a mismatch issue with values in the database tables that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `like`, you might need to add the wildcards:

```
SELECT RowNum 
from (Select ID, Name, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) from tblEncroachmentTypes) as temp
where temp.Name Like '%'+(Select EN_TYPE from LakeEncroachments WHERE EN_ID = '0526')+'%'
```

reformat looks like this:

```
select RowNum
from (
 select ID
  , name
  , RowNum = row_number() over (
   order by ID
   )
 from tblEncroachmentTypes
 ) as temp
where temp.name like '%' + (
  select EN_TYPE
  from LakeEncroachments
  where EN_ID = '0526'
  ) + '%'
```

Also, if your sub query for `like` returns more than one value, you'll need a different approach.

Comment: I am still getting 0 results returned.

Comment: Can you give us the value `EN_TYPE` that matches `EN_ID = '0526'` and the `name` you think it should match to in `tblEncroachmentTypes`?

Comment: the Encroachment type for EN_ID 526 is Multi-slip dock and the Type in tblEncroachmentTypes is 'Multiple Slip Dock'. I think that this would be the issue. #facepalm

Comment: That would do that =\

Comment: It looks like I've had the correct query, but wrong database value inputted :*(

Answer (score 0):

if your subquery give multiple rows, use this query

```
WITH temp as
  (SELECT ID, Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as RowNum
  FROM tblEncroachmentTypes) AS temp
SELECT temp.RowNum 
FROM LakeEncroachments 
INNER JOIN temp ON temp.Name LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(LakeEncroachments.EN_TYPE, '-', '% '), ' ', '% ') + '%'
WHERE EN_ID = '0526'
```